# Pentaho Kettle sql uid

Tags: kettle, uid

I need to load data from a csv to database. Those tables also used by application code, and table primary keys are generated by hibernate **uid**.

How do I create these primary key uid from kettle?

I appreciate any help.

Thanks,
Sam

Answer (score 1):

Use the "Generate Random Value" step - this can generate uuids etc.